# SwiftUI: Group and Sum by Core Data Attribute

Tags: core-data, swiftui

The question is this: how do you group Core Data objects by attribute and then perform simple calculations (let's say, sum) on them?

I've found a few similar answers for this (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522546/core-data-group-by-monthly-and-sum)), but none seem conclusive and all are geared up towards Swift (whereas I am working on SwiftUI).

For example, I have a Core Data model that looks like this:

```
extension Items {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Items> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Items>(entityName: "Items")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var cost: Int16
    @NSManaged public var type: String
}
```

In the `Home()` view, I'd like to group by type and then find the total amount paid (i.e. sum of cost) for all objects in each type.

So far, I've tried making a special `group()` function (a bit like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59180698/how-to-properly-group-a-list-fetched-from-coredata-by-date)), but get the error message *"Cannot find 'i' in scope"*.

```
struct Home: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: Items.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Items.type, ascending: true)]) var items: FetchedResults<Items>

var body: some View {
        ForEach(group(items), id: \.self) { [i] in
            Text("\([i].cost.reduce(0,+))")
           }
      }
}

func group(_ result : FetchedResults<Items>)-> [[Items]] {
        
    return Dictionary(grouping: result) { $0.type }
            .sorted(by: {$0.key < $1.key})
            .map {$0.value}
        
    }
```

Surely this can't be so hard? Any help very welcome!

Comment: You should not have brackets around the `i` in `[i] in`. Brackets like that *capture* a value, but you don't have a variable to capture -- you're just getting a parameter for the closure. Same think on the next line -- no brackets there either. There may be issues beyond this as well -- it would be good to see the source for `Clothing`

Comment: Thanks, I would love this to be the answer but when I try I get the message *"Value of type '[Items]' has no member 'cost'"*. `Clothing` should read `Items`, too (apologies, this was a mistake and I corrected it in the question).

Comment: Yeah, like I said, there may be additional issues. You're returning a multidimensional array from `group`, so you have to unwrap that first. Maybe you mean `i.map { $0.cost }.reduce(0,+)`

Comment: Nice, this worked perfectly! Feel free to submit this as an answer if you'd like :-) Many thanks in either case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have brackets around the i in [i] in. Brackets like that capture a value, but you don't have a variable to capture -- you're just getting a parameter for the closure.

```
ForEach(group(items), id: \.self) { i in
```

On your next line, you're dealing with a multidimensional array. You can't access a property directly, but you could `map` first:

```
Text("\(i.map(\.cost).reduce(0,+))")
```

You could also structure this slightly differently and remove the map by doing:

```
i.reduce(0,{ $0 + $1.cost })
```